# Gradle build fails with same string name for different product

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a project in which I have same string name but have diiferent values for based on the product like below

```
 <string name="no_storage" product="nosdcard">Insert SD card before using camera</string>
 <string name="no_storage" product="default">Insert SD card before using camera</string>
```

But while building using gradle I receive below errror

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'
Error: Found item String/no_storage more than one time
```

Is there a way to bypass this check or resolve this issue ?

Comment: By different product, you mean different flavors or different buildTypes?

Comment: I don't think that there is a `product` attribute. You should use different resource sets for different build types/flavors

Answer (score 0):

You should put the string values in the appropriate flavor-related directories:

`src/nosdcard/res/strings.xml` (remove `product="nosdcard"` attribute):

```
<string name="no_storage">Insert SD card before using camera</string>
```

`src/main/res/stringx.xml` (remove `product="default"` attribute):

```
<string name="no_storage">Insert SD card before using camera</string>
```

I'm assuming that the `default` "product" means the default source set. For details, read the [documentation on build variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#sourcesets).